# org.hibernate.WrongClassException when loading entity via hibernate with abstract class inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

**Question :**

Do I need to remove generic on my interface IAbstractUserService ?

Is it related to this answer with type erasure ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31266152/6698175

**Problem :**

I'm getting this exception :

`org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [com.faz.idb.models.Adviser] : loaded object was of wrong class class com.faz.idb.models.Customer`

when trying to load entity with :

```
T getUserByEmail(String email);
```

like so :

```
AbstractUserServiceImpl<? extends AbstractUser> userService;
AbstractUser user = userService.getUserByEmail(email);
```

**Currently I have :**

`hibernate v7.0.3.Final`

An abstract parent class : AbtrsactUser

Child classes: Customer and Adviser ;

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "user_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "customer", value = Customer.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "adviser", value = Adviser.class)
})
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public abstract class AbstractUser { ........ }


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("adviser")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public class Adviser extends AbstractUser { ........ }


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("customer")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public class Customer extends AbstractUser { ........ }
```

**Service :**

```
public interface IAbstractUserService<T extends AbstractUser> {
        T getUserByEmail(String email);
```

**Implementation :**

```
@Service public class AbstractUserServiceImpl<T extends AbstractUser> implements IAbstractUserService<T> {

    @Autowired
    private AbstractUserRepository<T> userRepository;

    @Override
    public T getUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(null);
    }
```

**Repository :**

@Repository
public interface AbstractUserRepository extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
Optional findByEmail(String email);
}

**Generated SQL :**

> Hibernate: select abstractus0_.id as id2_0_, abstractus0_.email as
> email3_0_, abstractus0_.password as password4_0_,
> abstractus0_.user_type as user_typ1_0_ from abstract_user abstractus0_
> where abstractus0_.user_type in ('adviser', 'customer') and
> abstractus0_.email=?
>
> Hibernate: select person0_.customer_id as customer1_5_0_,
> person0_.first_name as first_na2_5_0_, person0_.gender as
> gender3_5_0_, person0_.last_name as last_nam4_5_0_, adviser1_.id as
> id2_0_1_, adviser1_.email as email3_0_1_, adviser1_.password as
> password4_0_1_ from person person0_ left outer join abstract_user
> adviser1_ on person0_.customer_id=adviser1_.id where
> person0_.customer_id=? 2022-03-14 06:14:34.029
>
> INFO 79095 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  :  HHH000327: Error
> performing load command

**In my database I have only one user :**

user_type | id | email       | password

customer  | 1  | xyz@live.fr | ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

I was using @MapsId without @JoinColumn(name="id") in the child entity of @OneToOne relation.

**Explanation:**

"AbstracUser" is extended by a "Customer" entity and he has @OneToOne relation with "PersonDetails".

So in Customer I had :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "Customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
cascade {CascadeType.ALL}, optional = false)  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  private PersonDetails person;
```

And PersonDetails :

```
@MapsId()
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Customer customer;
```

The solution was to add the referenced column in

```
@MapsId("id")
```

or

```
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name="id")
```

N.B

- Also make sure you syncronize both sides of a relation by "setting" their corresponding object. ([ressource I used](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/))
- For a better architecture, I Finally  ended up putting the @OneToOne relation inside the "AbstractUser" entity (not in Customer).